# If $L$ is a chain, prove it is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need ideas on the following problem. Suppose $L$ is a poset and every subset $S$ of $L$ has a top and bottom element. Prove $L$ is a finite chain.

All I need to do is prove that $L$ is finite (I have already proved $L$ is a chain). Any ideas or suggestions on solving this problem would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to relate to your question.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: I am certain that this was asked within the past month. If I weren't usin my iPhone I would have found the link.

Comment: Yes, it was asked within the last month. However, that link didn't provide any clear solution. I don't exactly know what they mean by L\{xo, x1, ... , xn}

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412698/a-set-is-a-finite-chain-if-every-subset-has-a-top-and-bottom-element

Comment: Feel free to leave a comment on my answer there. I'd be glad to explain anything about it that you like. In particular, $$L\setminus\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$$ means the set containing all elements of $L$, **except** for $x_0,x_1,...,x_n.$ Does that clarify things? (P.S.: I just edited my answer to fix a bonehead mistake. Take another look and see what you think.)

Comment: Oops! It just occurred to me that you probably don't have enough reputation to comment on that answer, yet. Given that, feel free to ask me anything here! If you put your questions as a comment on my answer below, then the site will alert me, and I'll be along to answer your questions as soon as I get the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've proved that $L$ is a chain, so since every non-empty subset of $L$ has a bottom element, then $L$ is well-ordered.

Thus, $L$ is order-isomorphic to a unique ordinal, say $\alpha$. Can you show that $\alpha$ must be finite? (**Hint**: Use the fact that every subset of $L$ has a *top* element.)

---

Alternate approach (related to my answer to this question, asked previously by another user): Let $x_0$ be the least element of $L,$ $x_1$ the second least element of $L,$ and so on. This sequence is well-defined recursively, because every non-empty subset of $L$ has a bottom element--so $x_1$ is the bottom element of the subset of $L$ containing all but $x_0$, $x_2$ is the bottom element of the subset of $L$ containing all but $x_0$ and $x_1,$ etc.--and at some point, this process must stop (namely, when we reach the top element of $L$) after finitely-many steps. If not, then the set of all $x_n$ (with $n$ a nonnegative integer) is a subset of $L$ without a top element! (Why?) This contradicts our assumption. Thus, our process will stop after finitely-many steps (say at $x_n$), giving us an increasing finite sequence $x_0,x_1,...,x_n$ of points of $L$. Show that every point of $L$ is in this sequence (use the recursive definition), and you're done.

Comment: I don't fully understand your proof:

"Now, suppose that L is not finite. Let x0 be the top element of L, and for any nonnegative integer n, let xn+1 be the top element of L∖{x0,...,xn}. Show that {xn:n a nonnegative integer} is a subset of L without a bottom element--the desired contradiction (you'll need the assumption that L isn't finite)."

That's in your other link. Do you mind breaking it down some more?

Comment: No problem at all. See my updated (hopefully clearer) answer above.

Comment: If the top element is in the complement of L,  then that means there is no top element in L. true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. "If the top element (*of what set?*) is in the complement of $L$ (*relative to what set?*), then that means there is no top element in $L$." Are you asking about the first approach above, or the second one? If you're asking about the second one, then are you trying to determine the answer to my parenthetical "Why?" above?