# A misconception in set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let  L  be  a  set  where  every  subset  of  L  has  a  top  and  bottom  element.  So  clearly  L  is  a  chain.  Now  if  L  is  a  countably  infinite  set.  And  as  L  is  a  chain  we  can  arrange  it  like  y$\leq$x1$\leq$x2$\leq$...$\leq$xn...$\leq$Y  [where  y  and  Y  are  the  bottom  and  top  elements  of  L].  Thus  every  subset  of  L  has  a  top  and  bottom  element,  but  not  a  finite  chain.  Where  am  I  doing  it  wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such an $L$, the subset $L\setminus\{Y\}$ has no greatest element, so it does not satisfy your hypothesis.

Comment: By this, do you mean that the hypothesis that every subset of $L$ has a top and bottom element, and the hypothesis that $L$ is countably infinite are impossible to satisfy simultaneously? If so, how would you prove that?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/412717/86856